# Managing many azure subscriptions with terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

In our organiztion we have a team which manages central azure services like vpn gateway, firewall, bastion etc. It should also provision subscriptions for our software development teams, which involves managing users and groups, creating a vnet and peering it with the hub etc. The development teams manage all other relevant resources in their subscriptions.

I couldn't find an efficient way to build the IaC around the subscription management process. It seems to me, that you have to run terraform for each subscription separately, since you have to provide a subscription id in the terraform azure provider. This seems a bit complicated to me, I would rather define all subscriptions in a single file and let terraform manage them in a single run, like this:

```
subscriptions = {
    "my-subscription-1" = {
        vnet_address_space    = ["10.0.4.0/27"],
        snet_address_prefixes = ["10.0.4.0/27"],
        users = [
            "abc@example.com",
            "def@example.com",
        ],
        groups = [
            "MyAD-Group",
        ]
    },
    "my-subscription-2" = {
        vnet_address_space    = ["10.0.4.32/27"],
        snet_address_prefixes = ["10.0.4.32/27"],
        users = [
            "efg@example.com",
            "hij@example.com",
        ],
        groups = [
            "AnotherAD-Group",
        ]
    }
}
```

I know that you can define multiple providers in terraform and assign alias names, but this only works until you have 5-6 subscriptions. In my case I need to manage 50 subscriptions.

Did I miss something? How do you manage your subscriptions?

Answer (score 0):

You must set **[Multiple Provider Configurations](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/providers/configuration#alias-multiple-provider-configurations)**

```
provider "azurerm" {
    subscription_id = "SUBSCRIPTION 1 ID"
    features {}
}

provider "azurerm" {
    alias           = "subscription2"
    subscription_id = "SUBSCRIPTION 2 ID"
    features {}
}
```

Then, when you will run a module, you must set the alias, for example:

```
# Create a Resource Group in subscription 1
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg1" {
    name     = "RG-subscription-1"
    location = "eastus"
}


# Create a Resource Group in subscription 2
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg2" {
    provider = azurerm.subscription2 # this is the alias previously defined 
    name     = "RG-subscription-2"
    location = "eastus"
}
```

Hope this helps!