azurerm_app_service_source_control creates a very outdated GubHub Action workflow
I am using terraform to set up resources in an Azure cloud. These resources includes an Azure App Function for which I host the source code on a private GitHub repository.
When using azurerm_app_service_source_control to set up the source control, it generates an GitHub Action workflow file that use tools that are so outdated that I need to manually updates the versions to make it work.
Here are the snippets of the terraform code that I believe is relevant for my question.

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"
}

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74735576/managing-many-azure-subscriptions-with-terraform
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = terraform.workspace == "prod" ? var.prod_subscription_id : var.dev_subscription_id
  tenant_id       = terraform.workspace == "prod" ? var.tenant_id : var.tenant_id
  client_id       = terraform.workspace == "prod" ? var.prod_client_id : var.dev_client_id
  client_secret   = terraform.workspace == "prod" ? var.prod_client_secret : var.dev_client_secret
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_source_control_token" "source_control_token" {
  type         = "GitHub"
  token        = var.github_token
  token_secret = var.github_token
}

resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "func_app" {
  name                = "func-${terraform.workspace}"
  location            = var.locations.long
  resource_group_name = var.rg.name

  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.func_plan.id
  storage_account_name       = var.storage_account.name
  storage_account_access_key = var.storage_account.primary_access_key

  site_config {
    application_stack {
      python_version = "3.10"
    }
  }

  app_settings = {
    "COSMOSDB_CONNECTIONSTRING" = var.cosmosdb_connection_string
    cors                        = "*"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  #### TODO: REMOVE BEFOR GOING TO PROD
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }

}

# Adding GitHub source control integration
resource "azurerm_app_service_source_control" "source_control" {
  app_id   = azurerm_linux_function_app.func_app.id
  repo_url = local.github_repo
  branch   = terraform.workspace == "prod" ? "main" : "dev"

  depends_on = [azurerm_linux_function_app.func_app]

  github_action_configuration {
    code_configuration {
      runtime_stack   = "python"
      runtime_version = "3.10"
    }
  }
}

The GitHub Action file generated looks like this:
name: Azure App Service - Build and Deploy Python App

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    # checkout the repo
    - name: 'Checkout Github Action'
      uses: actions/checkout@master


    - name: Set up Python version
      uses: actions/setup-python@v1
      with:
        python-version: '3.10'

    - name: Build using AppService-Build
      uses: azure/appservice-build@v2
      with:
        platform: python
        platform-version: '3.10'

    - name: Run Azure webapp deploy action using publish profile credentials
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: func-dev
        slot-name: Production
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_<REDACTED> }}

In order to have the workflow to build and deploy without error I need to manually go over the workflow and update all tools used to the latest versions.
There is no error in the logged output. The flow runs to the end and I get a notification that the workflow failed. The deploy step is not executed (but without output saying why), and that is why I started to look into the build step.
name: Azure App Service - Build and Deploy Python App

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Set up Python version
      uses: actions/setup-python@v5
      with:
        python-version: '3.10'

    - name: Build using AppService-Build
      uses: azure/appservice-build@v3
      with:
        platform: python
        platform-version: '3.10'
        source-directory: '.'

    - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: func-dev
        slot-name: Production
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_<REDACTED> }}

Since the updated version of the GH Actions flow works, I am confident that the error is not about authentication or similar.
I will deploy and take down servers somewhat frequently and would not like to have to make this update manually.
Is there a workaround where I can make the outdated file to work? I am not using docker. I am using VS Code's extension to set up my app function using Python version 1.
Or can provide a template in terraform with the updated GitHub action workflow?

Are you still facing the same issue. @TheIceBear

Yes, but I solved it using a workaround where I wrote a script the updates outdated workflows in my repos where this is used. I made that work but feels like a there should be a better solution.

Hello TheIceBear, seems like you have already found a workaround for your problem, I am suggesting few alternative ways, please feel free to add your inputs or your workaround solution to this as it may help other folks having similar problem on SO.
what I understood from the problem is that your code automatically generates a GitHub Action workflow with outdated dependencies, and you wanted to avoid manually updating these workflows after each deployment, so you wrote a post deployment script as a workaround.
I personally feel easiest way is we can manually integrate the GitHub Action workflow directly into the repo and disable auto-generation of the workflow.
For example, you can remove github_action_configuration block
Something like this-
name: Azure App Service - Build and Deploy Python App

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Set up Python version
      uses: actions/setup-python@v5
      with:
        python-version: '3.10'

    - name: Build using AppService-Build
      uses: azure/appservice-build@v3
      with:
        platform: python
        platform-version: '3.10'
        source-directory: '.'

    - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: func-dev
        slot-name: Production
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_<REDACTED> }}

But since you are saying you don't want to do this manually then other way which I think you have tried is use a local-exec provisioner to run a post-deployment script that updates the workflow file automatically.
#!/bin/bash
git clone git@github.com:abc-corp/arko.git
cd arko

# Update the workflow file with the correct action versions
sed -i 's/actions\/checkout@master/actions\/checkout@v4/' .github/workflows/azure.yml
sed -i 's/actions\/setup-python@v1/actions\/setup-python@v5/' .github/workflows/azure.yml
sed -i 's/azure\/appservice-build@v2/azure\/appservice-build@v3/' .github/workflows/azure.yml


git commit -am "Update GitHub Action workflow to latest versions"
git push origin main

